# Can't find free tier usage on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can't find free tier usage on AWS, where I can find the option below:

**(Aws only answer with automatic messages)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS free tier usage limits are clearly defined in its [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all) availability

To view how much of your AWS limits you have used, sign into AWS and go to the Billing Dashboard (https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home), there you should see a tile titled

> Top Free Tier Services by Usage

Comment: I don't know what you did but the free tier usage table has only just appeared.